# case statement in where condition

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-like, case-statement

In below script,it is showing 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE''.i am using CASE statement for checking length of F_TEXT_CODE>10. IF it is length>10 then i am using like operator if it is less than 10 i am using '=' operator.
how to achieve this logic in where condition?.

```
DECLARE
@MANU NVARCHAR(4000)='MANU0071'
BEGIN
SELECT   TOP 1000 TP.F_PRODUCT AS ID,
         TP.F_PRODUCT_NAME AS NAME
        FROM PDF_DETAILS TP
    LEFT JOIN V_PROD_ALIAS_MANU MAN ON MAN.F_PRODUCT = TP.F_PRODUCT
    WHERE TP.F_PRODUCT<>''AND 
        (CASE WHEN LEN(MAN.F_TEXT_CODE)>10 THEN
    (MAN.F_TEXT_CODE) LIKE @MANU 
    ELSE MAN.F_TEXT_CODE = @MANU END) AND 
       (TP.F_CUSTOM5 IS NULL OR TP.F_CUSTOM5 = '') 

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `case` like that.
`case` is an expression that returns a scalar value based on condition(s).
It can't be used as a flow-control element.

The logic you are describing can be accomplished using a combination of `or` and `and`:

```
DECLARE @MANU NVARCHAR(4000)='MANU0071'
BEGIN
SELECT   TOP 1000 TP.F_PRODUCT AS ID,
         TP.F_PRODUCT_NAME AS NAME
        FROM PDF_DETAILS TP
    LEFT JOIN V_PROD_ALIAS_MANU MAN ON MAN.F_PRODUCT = TP.F_PRODUCT
    WHERE TP.F_PRODUCT<>''
    AND 
    ( 
        (LEN(MAN.F_TEXT_CODE)>10 AND MAN.F_TEXT_CODE LIKE @MANU)
        OR
        (LEN(MAN.F_TEXT_CODE)<=10 AND MAN.F_TEXT_CODE = @MANU)
    ) 
    AND 
       (TP.F_CUSTOM5 IS NULL OR TP.F_CUSTOM5 = '') 
END
```

However, please note that using `like` without any wildcards will return the same result as using `=`, so the entire thing can be written like this

```
DECLARE @MANU NVARCHAR(4000)='MANU0071'
BEGIN
SELECT   TOP 1000 TP.F_PRODUCT AS ID,
         TP.F_PRODUCT_NAME AS NAME
        FROM PDF_DETAILS TP
    LEFT JOIN V_PROD_ALIAS_MANU MAN ON MAN.F_PRODUCT = TP.F_PRODUCT
    WHERE TP.F_PRODUCT<>''
    AND 
    AND MAN.F_TEXT_CODE = @MANU
    AND 
       (TP.F_CUSTOM5 IS NULL OR TP.F_CUSTOM5 = '') 

END:
```

Comment: i am using '%MANU0071%' in input parameter.i forgot to mention in input parameter

Comment: So you might want to use `replace(@MANU, '%', '')` when you want `=` and not `like`

Comment: Thank you.i will try it.

Comment: Glad to help :-)